# limsup and quotient of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $r\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}},\left\{ b_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=r$. Find $\limsup a_{n}$ and $\limsup b_{n}$

Comment: $b_n=n$ and $a_n=n\sqrt{2}$ then the limit goes to $\sqrt{2}$ and the limsup are $\infty$. I don't think you can say anything about the limsup. You are first looking ate ratio between the two this can happen everywhere.